# why $\zeta_n = e^{2\pi i / n}$, why for p prime divides n, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \supset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When I follow the argument,

> ($\zeta_n = e^{2\pi i / n}$,) if p prime divides n, $\zeta_p^n = 1$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \supset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$

I did not get the point why we can conclude the containing relationship. Can someone help and explain it more in details, thanks.

Comment: It's actually because $\zeta_{n}^{n/p}=\zeta_p,$ More generally, $k(\alpha)\subseteq k(\beta)$ if and only if $\alpha\in \mathbb k(\beta).$

Comment: But I suppose you could say that $x^n-1$ splits in: $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ (which requires proof) and thus, since $\zeta_p^n=1,$ you have $\zeta_p\in \mathbb Q(\zeta_n).$

Comment: The inequality you do get is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if you know that $x^n-1$ splits in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ (which requires proof,) the we could say:

> Since $\zeta_p^n=1,$ you have $\zeta_p\in \mathbb Q(\zeta_n).$

More generally, $k(\alpha)\subseteq k(\beta)$ if and only if $\alpha\in k(\beta).$

It is much easier to show that $\zeta_p\in\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ if $p\mid n.$ Namely: 
'
$$\zeta_p = \zeta_n^{n/p}.$$

Comment: I understand the second argument. For the first one, I have not touch splitting field yet, but I will check it out later. Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the concept of splitting field. It’s just that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ is the intersection of all fields containing $\zeta_p$, and $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is one of these.